# Laravel 5.4 How to update profile of applicant guest that is logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel and I want to let the user update his/her profile when logged in. I want to get the ID of the user when updating his/her profile but when I click on the edit view to pass the data using the id I got this error:

> ```
> (1/1) ErrorException
> Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Applicant\HomeController::edit()
> ```

Here is the code to my controller:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $applicant = $this->applicantRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($applicant)) {
            Flash::error('Applicant');

            return redirect(route('applicant.home'));
        }

        return view('applicant-dashboard.edit')->with('applicants', $applicant);
    }

    public function update($id, UpdateApplicantRequest $request)
    {
        $applicant = $this->applicantRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($applicant)) {
            Flash::error('Applicant not found');

            return redirect(route('applicant.index'));
        }

        $input = $request->all();

        $cashier = $this->applicantRepository->update([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($input['password']),
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'cellphone_no' => $input['cellphone_no']], $id);

        Flash::success('Profile updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('applicant.index'));
    }
```

Here is the code in my routes file:

```
Route::get('/edit', 'HomeController@edit')->name('applicant.edit');
```

Here is the code in my blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Applicant Profile
        </h1>
   </section>
   <div class="content">
       {{-- @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors') --}}
       <div class="box box-primary">
           <div class="box-body">
               <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px">
                   {!! Form::model($applicant, ['route' => ['applicant.update', $applicant->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

                        @include('applicant-dashboard.fields')

                   {!! Form::close() !!}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
@endsection
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` into your route:

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'HomeController@edit')->name('applicant.edit');
```

Comment: I changed it but it says:
Missing required parameters for [Route: applicant.edit] [URI: applicant/edit/{id}].

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of that error to your post? I have a feeling you're not passing an id to the route somewhere. I will update my answer after you've done that

Comment: In your menu.php file you must have a link to edit your "applicant" yeah? So, change it so you're also passing through the applicant. Like: route('applicant.edit', $applicant); sorry about the lack of highlighting, I can't find backticks on my phone.

Comment: Its okay atleast your helping. Btw I will change my route to route('applicant.edit', $applicant); in my menu file and ro my web.php routes into /edit/{applicant} like that?

Comment: Its okay atleast your helping. Btw I will change my route to route('applicant.edit', $applicant); in my menu file and ro my web.php routes into /edit/{applicant} like that?

Comment: It doesn't matter about changing the route itself, just do the first thing you mentioned.

Comment: Join me on live chat and I will help you further https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151473/room-for-aaron-fahey-and-jayz-de-vera

Answer (score 0):

You pass the ID into web.php:

```
Route::get('edit/{ID}', 'HomeController@edit')->name('applicant.edit');
```

Comment: I did that it says undefined variable id in my menu.blade.php but I tried to pass the id of the user login in my controller